# Why does List.add(E) return boolean while List.Add(int, E) returns void?

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

Looking at the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29) I saw the that an ArrayList has an overloaded add method:

> public boolean add(E e)
>
> Appends the specified element to the end of this list.

and

> public void add(int index,
>        E element)
>
> Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list. Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).

I noticed that the first one returned a `boolean` while the second one was a `void`. As it turns out, the first `add` HAS to return a `boolean` because:

> Returns:
>       true (as specified by Collection.add(E))

So I went to [Collection.add(E)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add%28E%29):

> boolean add(E e)
>
> Ensures that this collection contains the specified element (optional operation). Returns true if this collection changed as a result of the call. (Returns false if this collection does not permit duplicates and already contains the specified element.)

So my question is, why is `add` specified to return boolean instead of being a void? When I `add` something I would expect to only do an operation.

I understand that there's other data structures that, as opposed to ArrayList, do not allow duplicates (such as sets). But even then, couldn't the problem be solved along the lines of:

```
public void add(E e){
    if(e is not in set){
        add e;
    }
}
```

That way if `e` IS in the set no action is taken. Why is it better to return a `boolean` instead of the `void` approach?

Comment: My guess is because sometimes you might want to know if you failed to put something into a set. If `void` is returned there's no way of knowing short of looking for the element after. Can't think of any relevant examples off the top of my head though...

Comment: Your code wouldn't do the same job because it doesn't let the caller know if it already contained the object. Equivalent code would have a .contains before the .add

Comment: If you don't care about whether the call to `add` caused any changes, you're not obligated to do anything with the result. But other people might find the information useful.

Comment: A usage example is one I recently used: a processing queue and a searching algorithm that looks at tiles and adds neighbours to the queue only if the neighbour is new (or else you would search forever if you curve back on itself ). Obviously could be implemented in several different ways but this is one

Comment: Another benefit to consider is atomicity in case of synchronized collections.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`Collection.add` is a pretty generic method (not in the sense of Java generics -- in the sense of being widely applicable). As such, they wanted a return value that would apply generally.

Some classes (like `ArrayList`) always accept elements, and so will always return `true`. You're right that in these cases, a return type of `void` would be just as good.

But others, like `Set`, will sometimes not allow an element to be added. In `Set`'s case, this happens if an equal element was already present. It's often helpful to know that. Another example is a bounded collection (that can only hold a certain number of elements).

You could ask, "can't code just check this manually?" For instance, with a set:

```
if (!set.contains(item)) {
    set.add(item);
    itemWasAdded(item);
}
```

This is more verbose than what you can do now, but not a whole lot:

```
if (set.add(item)) {
    itemWasAdded(item);
}
```

But this check-then-act behavior isn't thread safe, which can be crucial in multithreaded applications. For instance, it could be that another thread added an equal item between you checking `set.contains(item)` and the `set.add(item)` in the first code snippet. In a multithreaded scenario, those two actions really need to be a single, atomic action; returning `boolean` from the method makes that possible.

Comment: `not in the sense of Java generics` - thank GOD! :) +1, good answer.

Comment: Checking and then adding could also be potentially inefficient for some kinds of implementations, so it's nice the API allows you to do that in a better way for those cases.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I do not agree with a detail. 'return type of void would be just as good'. Until now I did not find any situation where returning void would be a good idea. I would rather get the added object returned than void.

Answer (score 1):

because it is often useful to know if something was actually added, or alternately was already there.

Comment: This answer fits more as a comment.

Comment: all answers fit as a comment, the answer is actually in the javadocs -> `Returns:
    true if this collection changed as a result of the call` that says it all. ... unfair down vote btw...

Comment: @A4L it's not unfair. There's no explanation about the real reasons for this.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza isn't the reason is to know whether the element was newly added as result of the call or that it was already there and there was no need to replace it or it has been replaced? It's just a shot hand for `if(! col.contains(e)) col.add(e)`

Comment: @A4L the question is **why `List(int, E)` returns `void` while `List(E)` returns `true`**. And that's not covered here.

Comment: again, the answer is in the javadocs -> `Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list (optional operation). Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).` The `List` is always - unless an exception is thrown - altered as result of the call, so there is no need to return anything.

Comment: @A4L the answer may be in javadocs, but **it is not in this post**, so this **is not** an answer and doesn't deserve to be upvoted.

Comment: I agree with you, but it certainly answers half of OP's question and is not wrong and therefor maybe not worth an up vote but certainly not worth a down vote. The accepted answer is with regard to content exactly the same as this one as it does not answer the part about `List#add(int, E)`, it just a bit more elaborated, but so much up votes, that's just weird

Comment: +3 -3 down ... its a simple question, hence simple answer.

Comment: The reason I downvoted, the question was why those two calls have different return types.  If someone asked "Why do many Australian mammals have pouches, while it is rare elsewhere in the world?", I would downvote the answer: "So they can carry their babies".

Answer (score 1):

Because it's an extra information which doesn't cost anything and can be useful in certain situations. For example:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.add("foobar");
boolean wasAlreadyThere = set.add("foobar");
```

Otherwise you would have to do

```
boolean wasAlreadyThere = set.contains("foobar");
set.add("foobar");
```

which requires twice the work (first you have to lookup, then lookup again to add).

Comment: Not to get all pedantic, but... isn't the logic backwards in the first example?